# Get Click event for CTreeViewCtrl

Tags: wtl

I mean click on element of treeview - > it show sth in listview.

I create controls like this(where tree and list - > CTreeViewCtrl and CListViewCtrl)

```
    split.Create(*this,rcDefault,NULL,0,WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE);
    RECT rlist,rtree;
    list.Create(split,rlist,CListViewCtrl::GetWndClassName(),WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | LVS_REPORT | LVS_EDITLABELS, WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE);
    tree.Create(split,rtree,CTreeViewCtrl::GetWndClassName(),WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | LVS_REPORT | TVS_EDITLABELS, WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE);
    list.AddColumn(L"KEY",0);
    list.AddColumn(L"VALUE",1);
    split.SetSplitterPanes(tree,list);
```

What parameters will have   the event function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TVN_SELCHANGED notification code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773544%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Notifies a tree-view control's parent window that the selection has
>   changed from one item to another. This notification code is sent in
>   the form of a WM_NOTIFY message.

That is, when you click an item and it changes selection of treeview control, the control sends `WM_NOTIFY` message to its parent (such as your dialog) with code `TVN_SELCHANGED` and you are supposed to handle it.

Comment: `MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_NOTIFY,OnClickItem)`? And inside OnClickIted I should work with TVN_SELCHANGED?

Comment: `NOTIFY_HANDLER_EX(IDC_TREE_EXPLORER, TVN_SELCHANGED, OnExplorerTreeSelChanged)`, see http://forum.sources.ru/index.php?showtopic=274194&hl=

Comment: But I do not have IDC_TREE_EXPLORER

Comment: 1. you can assign identifier to your control, 2. there are other NOTIFY_ macros

Answer (score 0):

In your mainfrm.h

```
// ...
CTreeViewCtrlEx m_treeview;

// ...
BEGIN_MSG_MAP(CMainFrame)
// ...
NOTIFY_CODE_HANDLER(TVN_SELCHANGED, OnTVSelChanged)
END_MSG_MAP()
```

and

```
// mainfrm.h or mainfrm.cpp
LRESULT CMainFrame::OnTVSelChanged(int idCtrl, LPNMHDR pnmh, BOOL& bHandled)
{
  //...
}
```